# java - panel.getVisible?

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jpanel, visible

it may be a stupid question, but I didn't find anything on google etc...
So I have a panel, and want to know, if it is visible

```
if (pnlUnten.getVisible == false)
```

this one doesn't seem to work.

```
if (pnlUnten.isVisible == false)

if (pnlUnten.isVisible)
```

those both neither

I think there is a very easy solution for my problem, but I can't figure it out..

Comment: Forgot the parentheses?  Try `if (! pnlUnten.getVisible())`

Comment: By brackets I think you mean parentheses?

Comment: @Borgleader: Ah yes. you're right.

Comment: No it still doesn't work.

Maybe I need to import an extra package?


Here is the error, if you need

Telefonbuch.java:323:19: error: cannot find symbol
    if (! pnlUnten.getVisible()) {
                  ^
  symbol:   method getVisible()
  location: variable pnlUnten of type JPanel

Comment: He meant `isVisible()` not `getVisible()`.

Comment: Thanks it works! :)

How can I give the answer a "reward" or something like that?

Comment: @NickH., Typically, you'd hit the checkmark next to the answer, but there are no answers.

Comment: Hmm ok :/ 
Thax you're a great community!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like isVisible is only an indication of whether the panel is visible. If it's true, then it's visible if it's *parent* is visible. So if you want to use this property, it seems like you'd need to combine it with checking the parent. I had a quick go, but nothing thorough.

My code: `if (panel.isVisible() && panel.getParent().isVisible())`

Comment: An alternative would be to use `isShowing`. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22246071/6304917) question.

Answer (score 1):

`JPanel#getVisible()` isn't a method, but [`JPanel#isVisible()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isVisible%28%29) is, as inherited from Component.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is this:

```
//this code checks if its visible

if (pnlUntel.isVisible())
    //do something

//this code below checks if its not visible

if (!pnlUntel.isVisible())
    //do something
```

[Example]